# MEAN stack: first object pushed into MongoDB schema's array causes RangeError

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

edit: I have realized that this is hanging at the line "res.json(comment);" of my angular-ui-route. Still not sure why.

I'm following through the tutorial here: https://thinkster.io/tutorials/mean-stack. This may be related to the fact that the tutorial is a little outdated. I've uploaded my code in it's current state to http://github.com/orieporter/flappernews

It's a simple reddit clone web app for posting links, comments, and upvoting them. I am getting a "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error each time I add the first comment to a post. Subsequent comments work no problem. When I restart my node server and reload the page the comment that broke the server is there. Can anyone help me find the problem here?

Full error:

```
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at model.Document.$toObject (c:\Users\source\repos\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1962:24)
at model.Document.toJSON (c:\Users\source\repos\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2300:15)
at clone (c:\Users\source\repos\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:252:18)
at cloneArray (c:\Users\source\repos\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:362:14)
at clone (c:\Users\source\repos\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:247:12)
at cloneObject (c:\Users\source\repos\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:343:13)
at clone (c:\Users\source\repos\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:260:16)
at model.Document.$toObject (c:\Users\source\repos\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2009:13)
at model.Document.toJSON (c:\Users\source\repos\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2300:15)
at clone (c:\Users\source\repos\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:252:18)
at cloneObject (c:\Users\source\repos\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:343:13)
at clone (c:\Users\source\repos\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:260:16)
at model.Document.$toObject (c:\Users\source\repos\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2009:13)
at model.Document.toJSON (c:\Users\source\repos\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2300:15)
at clone (c:\Users\source\repos\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:252:18)
at cloneArray (c:\Users\source\repos\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:362:14)
at clone (c:\Users\source\repos\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:247:12)
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="addComment()" style="margin-top:30px;">
    <h3>Add a new comment</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" ng-model="body"></input>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
</form>
```

Angular Controller Function:

```
$scope.addComment = function () {
    if ($scope.body === '') { return; }
    posts.addComment(post._id, {
        body: $scope.body,
        author: 'user'
    },
    $scope.post);
    $scope.body = '';
};
```

Angular Factory Function:

```
o.addComment = function (id, comment, post) {
    return $http.post('/posts/' + id + '/comments', comment).then(function (response) {
        post.comments.push(response.data);
        return response.data;
    });
};
```

Relevant Express Route:

```
router.post('/posts/:post/comments', function (req, res, next) {
    var comment = new Comment(req.body);
    comment.post = req.post;

    comment.save(function (err, comment) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }

        req.post.comments.push(comment);
        req.post.save(function (err, post) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }

            res.json(comment);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment Schema:

```
var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    body: String,
    author: String,
    upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
    post: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }
});
```

Post Schema:

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    link: String,
    upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
    comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
});
```

Comment: The comment is not being saved here: `comment.post = req.post;` bc your request doesn't have a `post` attribute. It's trying to respond as an `err` but you haven't responded there, just returned the function. Or do you have another route that is receiving the `next(err)` call?

Comment: I get the post from a parameter in another part of my routes file. I can print req.post to console no problem and it looks fine. Once I set comment.post to req.post I can't print my comment to console. And again all of this only applies to the first comment I make on the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue and took me a bit (few fun hours!) of console log debugging, Google searching, and thinkster slack hair-pulling to try to figure out what was going on. Mind you, I'm new to all of this, so wrapping my head around everything was probably the biggest challenge.

Upon further inspection, I narrowed down the cause to the `res.json(comment)` line as well for the create new comment route logic (routes/index.js).

Logically, I didn't understand why the whole comment object was being pushed to the post comments array when all that is needed is the comment object id. So naturally I eventually figured why not just pass the comment object id (comment._id) and see what happens. And wallah, it worked. No more `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

So that may address the issue, but my curiously stubborn self wants to know why the heck that would matter? Why does it happen only on the first comment for the post but works fine on the others?

```
router.post('/posts/:post/comments', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  var comment = new Comment(req.body);
  comment.post = req.post._id; // <-- originally 'req.post'
  comment.author = req.payload.username;

  comment.save(function(err, comment){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    req.post.comments.push(comment._id);  // <-- originally 'comment'
    req.post.save(function(err, post) {
      if(err){ return next(err); }

      res.json(comment);
    });
  });
});
```

I figured if mongoose was just going to need the post and comment ids and not the entire objects, then why not just save the ids. Storing the complete objects seemed to cause some sort of infinite loop I believe that causes a call stack error during the response. Perhaps because both objects reference each other? But then again, I'm not sure how this all really works so if any experts out there can shed some light, please do. But that should address the issue and hopefully help others. I should mention that this is an error in the actual Flapper News code they provide. I found that out by downloading their completed source code and running it.

Comment: Thanks Jashua, this is what helped me. I think you are definitely right about the infinite loop being caused by circular references in the Post and Comment documents.The fact that it works for subsequent comments makes me think that maybe in past versions of mongoose/mongodb that code would automatically take the ObjectID from an object added if you had defined is as an ObjectID.  I guess this is just another instance of their tutorial being outdated. I emailed Thinkster asking them to update it, hopefully they do!

Comment: No problem - I've messaged Thinkster as well. I'm just glad I wasn't the only one experiencing the issue and happy to have found your post. Good luck with everything.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `res.json(comment);` is trying to stringify the Comment object instance you've created on `var comment = new Comment(req.body);`

But the "stringifying" process is hanging obviously because of the Comment Object size (which is too big and doesn't have to be stringified).

You should be replacing `res.json(comment);` by something like

`res.json({ status: "success" });`

Comment: I have no problem using res.json() on my other objects and on my subsequent comments on the same post, it's only the first one that causes the crash.